# Change the Page layout when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the layout of a page that has 3 columns:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

... to 4 columns when a button is clicked:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have no clue on how to do this.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. Depending on that you may not need specific column count classes. What have you tried? You're expected to make and show your effort. And it's not at all clear where the fourth column comes from or what should be in it. Please revise to add detail and show some scripting. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can add another div. Here is my approach :

```js
function appendDiv(){
  let row = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
//   change className for all the col-md-4 div
  document.querySelectorAll('.col-md-4').forEach(function(item) {
   item.className = 'col-md-3';
  })
  //create new div;
  let col = document.createElement('div');
//   add classname to div
  col.className = "col-md-3"
  row[0].appendChild(col)
}
```

```css
    .col-md-4{
  border : 1px solid blue;
      height : 20px;
}
    .col-md-3{
       border : 1px solid green;
      height : 20px;
    }
```

```html
 <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
      <button onClick='appendDiv()'>click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways this could be done depending on your data, however, here's one angle.

If you have both your 4 column & 3 column versions of the data loaded on the page (but one hidden with css). You could run something like this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="colsThree" class="displayArea show">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="colsFour" class="displayArea">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="changeColumns">Click Me To Change Columns</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
const buttonEl = document.querySelector("#changeColumns");

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const outputEls = document.querySelectorAll('.displayArea')
  outputEls.forEach((outputEl) => {
    outputEl.toggle("show")
  })
});
```

**CSS**

```
.displayArea {
  display: none;
}

.displayArea.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and `appendChild` method.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')

btn.onclick = function() {
const targetClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.col-md-4')
targetClasses.forEach((tag, idx) => {
tag.className = 'col-md-3'

const lastIdx = targetClasses.length - 1
if (idx === lastIdx) {
const tag = document.createElement('div')
, row = document.querySelector('.row')
tag.className = 'col-md-3'
tag.innerText = '4'
row.appendChild(tag)
}
})

console.log(targetClasses)

return
}
```

```html
<div>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using vanilla HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, then one of the ways to achieve this is by adding a click listener to the button beforehand. *FYI: for brevity's sake, I'll call the div element with `row` class as **parent***. When user clicks the button, then it should

1. remove `col-md-4` class and add `col-md-3` class to all the children elements of **parent**.
2. add a new div element with `col-md-3` class into **parent**.

Here's a [link](https://codepen.io/sebikawa/pen/abYMmJv) to the codepen for your reference.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const rowDiv = document.querySelector('.row');

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  Array.from(rowDiv.children).forEach(childDiv => {
    childDiv.classList.remove('col-md-4');
    childDiv.classList.add('col-md-3');
  });
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.classList.add('col-md-3');
  rowDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
  
  // I disabled the button to prevent the user
  // from clicking it the second time.
  e.target.disabled = true;
});
```

```css
.button-parent {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.row {
  height: 100vh;
}

.row > div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.row > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}

.row > div:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.row > div:nth-child(4) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="button-parent">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add div</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```